# Use last arguments from vim's :make command

Tags: vim

I have a one key mapping to build my project.

```
noremap <F5> :make<CR>
```

This works great.  However I sometimes am building a only a piece of the project.  In this case I use the command `:make smaller_part` to build just that piece.  I'd also like a one key mapping for this use case as well.

```
noremap <S-F5> :make last_arguments()<CR>
```

Is this possible?  A `last_arguments()` function isn't required.  It's just how I imagine the solution would look.  The important part is I hit one key and it runs :make with the arguments that I gave it last time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use

```
map <f2> :wa<cr>:Make <Up>
```

to run make with the last arguments
by the way

```
command -nargs=* Make write | make <args> | cwindow 6
```

is the Make.

Comment: Nice!
(And I need many characters for making a comment, wich I think is not that good of an idea, since sometimes a short comment can be positive. Also, the game)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you can programmatically retrieve the last line from the command history, or specific arguments on it. I expect you can, but I don't know how to do it offhand.

But what are the constraints here? If you'll allow your initial invocation of `make` to call a function you've defined, say `:MyMake(smaller_part)`, then that can save the smaller_part in a variable and you can define a `Remake()` function that will call `make` on the target saved in that variable.

Is that solution acceptable to you? Or must the original invocation be of the form `:make smaller_part`?

Comment: I don't really care how :make is called custom commands would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

What if you wrap the :make command in a couple commands of your own? One command runs make with whatever argument you supplied (possibly none). It also stores the argument in a variable. Then you map this command to <F5>. The other command runs make with the argument stored in your variable (again, if any). You map this command to <S-F5>. I think the vim command for defining your own commands like this is Command.

Comment: How would you call make from a vim function passing the command all of the function parameters?